# 2 threads - one with opengl window and the second with wxwidgets one

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, opengl, wxwidgets

I'm writing an editor and I have a problem which means calling native file save/open dialog from my opengl app. The editor is written with my in-game opengl gui. So i came up with idea that when user press "load" or "save", I will create a thread which will create required (non-visible) wx window and it will call wxFileDialog and after the job is done I will delete that thread. Is it possible or maybe there are better aproaches to acces file open/save dialog in cross platform way from an opengl app?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "my opengl app".  OpenGL is a library, which can be called from apps written using various different frameworks, wxWidgets among them.  You should whatever File Save dialog your app framework offers.

Comment: Uh I forget to write it. The SFML manages window and it uses opengl for rendering. SFML of course doesn't have any gui functions. Also, by "opengl app" i mean "no gui app" (you know, something like a game).

Comment: Use only one framework. wxWidget has a OpenGL widget, use that instead of SFML.

Comment: Sorry it's a little misunderstood. SFML uses OpenGL internally for its rendering and I render through OpenGL but using SFML functions. So creating opengl widget won't help me, as my engine is in sfml.

Comment: I, for one, do not know what SFML is.  Perhaps you should tag your question with SFML, and maybe attract someone who does know.

Comment: The same as glut, it doesn't matter to the question really. The question is if a one process can have 2 independent windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already said, the simplest solution is to use wxWidgets for the main loop and [wxGLCanvas](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_g_l_canvas.html) for OpenGL stuff.

But if this is impossible, for some reason, you should indeed be able to use wxWidgets from another thread. Just remember that wxWidgets GUI functionality can only be used from a *single* thread so you need to initialize it from that thread too. And, of course, you'll need to handle thread synchronization yourself as wxWidgets won't know anything about the rest of your program.

Answer (score 2):

wxWidget has a OpenGL widget. Put your OpenGL stuff into this one, forward the event received by the widget to your GUI system, then you'll not have to battle for the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GLUT, or equivalent, then you do NOT have a cross-platform framework.  If you want a cross-platform app, then your will have to choose a framework ( e.g wxWidgets or Qt or whatever ) and proceed from there.  Otherwise, you can use the native calls to the windows API if you are on windows, and the equivalent on other platforms.

GLUT only gives you a console style application.  If you want a GUI, then you have to choose a GUI framework, even if you do not want cross-platform.  There as many to choose from, the choice mostly depends on which you are most familiar with.  Then you add the calls to the OpenGL library from you GUI application, however built.  This way, you do not have to muck around with multiple threads.

It may be that you have a massive investment in your GLUT application, and do not wish to discard it merely to get a few GUI capabilities.  In this case, I recommend building a new GUI app, separate from your GLUT application, which communicates with your existing app using a socket ( or other interprocess com system ) but runs in a separate process.  This way you will not encounter all the ghastly, hard to fix bugs, created by multithreaded apps.